# jQuery autocomplete not working for the first attempt

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, autocomplete

I have tried to implement dynamic autocomplete in my program. It is working perfectly after first input. But it doesn't show suggestions for the first attempt. However, server is responding the required source for autocomplete. Here is my code.

```
       $('.autocomplete').live('keyup', function(){
        $this = $(this);
        var search = $this.val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/package/index/search/keyword/'+search+'/format/json',
            async: false,
            success: function(res){
                //console.log(res.options);
                //console.log(res.defined_ids);
                staticObject = res.defined_ids;
                $this.autocomplete({
                    source: res.options
                });
            }
        });            
    });
```

Server side Code is

```
    $keyword = $this->_getParam('keyword');
    $elementDetailModel = new Package_Model_ElementDetail();
    $arr = $elementDetailModel->searchElementDetail($keyword);
    $this->view->options = $arr['options']; // returns in the format array("test2","my new test", "night stay in delux room")
    $this->view->defined_ids = $arr['defined_ids']; // returns in the format array(21::21=>"test2", 22::22=>"my new test", 24::24=>"night stay in delux room")
```

when I console logged defined_ids and options in firebug, I got following response when I typed 't' in the text field.
options:

> ["test2", "my new test", "night stay in delux room"]

defined_ids:

> Object { 21::21="test2", 22::22="my new test", 24::24="night stay in delux room"}

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably a server problem. What do you see in firebug? can you give us a fiddle?

Comment: I got this kind of response in firebug , ["test2", "my new test", "night stay in delux room"] for res.options

Comment: registry
 Object { Zend_View_Helper_Doctype={...}, Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry={...}, db={...}, more...}
 
path
 "/package/index"
 
options
 ["test2", "my new test", "night stay in delux room"]
 
0
 "test2"
 
1
 "my new test"
 
2
 "night stay in delux room"
 
defined_ids
 Object { 21::21="test2", 22::21="my new test", 24::24="night stay in delux room"}
 
21::21
 "test2"
 
22::21
 "my new test"
 
24::24
 "night stay in delux room" ...........Full response.

Comment: IMO, `["test2", "my new test", "night stay in delux room"]` is the format of the array not a json.

Comment: it should be like this   "options" : { "test2","my new test", "night stay in delux room"}  
         make the page returning the value, in this format

Answer (score 0):

The format displayed from the firebug, is not that of a JSON. It is an array, which are accessed using indices.

When you are displaying the output, make sure you `json_encode()` the array first, then display it.

For example, with respect to the question, you final array should look something like this

```
$array['options'] = array("test2", "my new test", "night stay in room");
//Then you should echo the encoded the array to json

echo json_encode($array);
```

Next, make sure you views are turned off this request.

Comment: response should be returned in a variable. So when I did json_encode, then I got following response which didn't work. options "["test2","my new test"]"

Comment: @BashantaDahal जी, You have to echo the json encoded variable. I can't help you unless I see more data and codes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need defined_ids as well because I need to assign variable staticObject = res.defined_ids after each request; Here is code of server side.. `code`

Comment: $keyword = $this->_getParam('keyword');
        $elementDetailModel = new Package_Model_ElementDetail();
        $arr = $elementDetailModel->searchElementDetail($keyword);
        //$arr['options'] returns in the format array('test', 'my new test')
        //$arr['defined_ids'] returns in the format array('2'=>'test', '23'=>'my new test')
        $this->view->options = $arr['options'];
        $this->view->defined_ids = $arr['defined_ids'];

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to specify the context sever-side. In you controller's `_init()`method, add:

```
$ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
$ajaxContext->addActionContext('actionName', 'json')
            ->initContext();
```

and make sure to replace `actionName` by you action controller name.

Then, `$this->view->options = $arr['options']` will automatically be converted in a valid json format.

More information about AjaxContext [here in the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done the exact same thing you have mentioned. But still, it's not working. It works after first attempt. I don't know why autocomplete is not working after first attempt

Comment: It's strange, we need more information about your problem to help you (what does Firebug say?). Also, did you consider using [ZendX_JQuery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zendx.jquery.html)? (`ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete`)

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope you can have more idea about my problem.